# Why multiple thread working even if setting sys.setswitchinterval(1000)

Tags: python, cpython, gil

In python3, `sys.getswitchinterval()` equal to 5ms, so GIL will be release every 5ms and some I/O operation. I set switchinterval to 1000 seconds, this means every thread will be switched in 1000 seconds by python interpreter if there is no I/O operation.In below code, i expected to see different value than 0, because for loop takes about 10-15 seconds

why not "a" different than 0 ?

```
from threading import Thread
import sys

sys.setswitchinterval(100000)

a=0
def increment(arg):
    global a
    for i in range(100000000):
        a=a+arg


for _ in range(30):
    t1=Thread(target=increment,args=(-1,))
    t2=Thread(target=increment,args=(1,))


    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    print(a)
    a=0


output:
0
0
0
...
```

Comment: How could you ever get a non-zero value? You're waiting for both threads to completely finish by calling `join()`. Just because t1 never yields the GIL to t2 doesn't mean that t2.join() won't wait for t2 to finish end-to-end: after t1.join() completes, there's no longer any competition.

Comment: I got your message i think, if t1 thread finish executing, t2 thread get GIL and start to execution even if setswitchinterval value equal to 1000, am i right ?

Comment: Yes, a thread that's finished can't hold the GIL.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `join` will wait for the target thread to finish execution - regardless of how long it takes to switch there.
There is, at the point you print `a` value, each thread had run until completion.
If you relocate your `print` to *after* `t1.join` and before `t2.join`, you might see imbalances resulting from your delayed switch interval - but keep in mind this is in no way reliable and this is onlyof some value for experimentation purposes.  If you really want control over task switching, use appropriate methods such as Locks and Semaphores.